# Alfresco webscripts run from non-admin users getting 401-Unauthorized

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-webscripts

I have created webscript in alfresco community edition-5.1.x , When non-admin users run the scripts not working I am getting `401-Unauthorized` when run from admin users its working fine, Can any help me how can I run webscript from non-admin users.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to check your [webscript definition](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.1/references/dev-extension-points-webscripts.html) :

The authentication part must be **user**. Other choices are admin (probably your case) or none (no authentication).

```
<webscript>
    <shortname>Hello World</shortname>
    <description>Hello World Sample Web Script that responds back with a greeting</description>
    <url>/tutorial/helloworld</url>
    <format default="html"></format>
    <authentication>user</authentication>
    <family>Alfresco Tutorials</family>
</webscript>
```

Comment: Another option is allowing guest access, and using AuthenticationUtil inside the controller in order to get a certain level of permissions.

Answer (score 0):

You can run your webscripts by non-admin user. You have to give the authentication tag of your webscript's desc file with the `runas="admin"` attribute, like this:

```
<authentication runas="admin">user</authentication>
```